# sanity shopify assets plugin fails

Tags: node.js, reactjs, shopify, content-management-system, sanity

This may be too vague, but ask any question and I will try to get code or give an explanation to troubleshoot this issue. We are using Sanity to build out a cms for our Shopify store, at this point we have integrated the sanity plugin into shopify and synced product and collection objects into sanity. The next step was to use the sanity-plugin-shopify-assets npm package/sanity plugin to fetch shopify assets and link them to content in sanity. However this fails with the message:

`An unexpected error occurred - check plugin configuration`
[image]

(sidenote: the "Add New" link works, which should mean that this isn't an issue with permissions or bad configurations to our store)

The shopify asset field was added to our schema as directed in the docs ([sanity plugin docs](https://github.com/sanity-io/sanity-plugin-shopify-assets)):

```
defineField({
    type: 'shopify.asset',
    name: 'shopifyAsset',
    title: 'Link To',
    description: 'Link that the banner should point to'
}),
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!